# Needed: Light and free HTML editor with source control support

Tags: html, version-control, ide

We're not doing real web development. We get our HTMLs from our designers, and have our web app generate those HTMLs (with some specific content). Simply put, we don't use any major web development infrastructure (ASP, PHP, JSP etc). Having that said, we sometimes do need to edit HTML, JavaScript and CSS files, and I'm tired of using rocks and stones and having no proper backup. What I'm looking for is a rather simple editor that would handle those kinds of files, and most importantly - will **support source control**, and will be free (or very cheep).

I've been looking into Aptana, and it seems to be a bit of an overkill. It has a lot of features we can do without, and this makes it too heavy. VWD express is lighter, but has no source control integration. There are probably a million other HTML editors, but I couldn't find one that satisfies the basic requirements - relatively lightweight, supports source control and is (almost) free. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly what you want but you could try and use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) combined with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).

Comment: Indeed not what I wanted, but after I read you suggestion I changed my mind... TortoiseSVN works for me, I'll just have to get used to managing the project in Windows Explorer rather than in an IDE. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is pretty good.  It's also very popular among developers and can edit HTML.

Why is supporting source control a requirement?  I find that the place for good source control is not in the editor.  The editor just gets in the way and only implements a subset of functionality.

Comment: Aptana is based on Eclipse. No doubt they are both great tools, but they are heavy. Running them in concur with our main IDE will choke a 2 years old PC. Wrt the SC integration, I'd like the IDE to work for me rather than the opposite...

Answer (score 0):

[NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org) can edit about anything, is free, cross-platform, and directly supports CVS, Subversion and Mercurial version control systems. It's not exactly lightweight, although it is lighter than any comparably featured competitors I'm aware of.

Comment: I love NetBeans and use it for Java development, but I was disappointed by how it handled HTML and JS, and I find it too heavy for a handy occasional HTML editor.

Answer (score 0):

Pick your poison at Wikipedia's [Comparison of HTML editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_editors) page.

Answer (score 0):

The [Revisionator](http://revisionator.com) is a cloud based html editor that has built in source control. It'll even do wysiwyg diffing and merging of different versions.

Comment: this is an deadlink